# U.S. East Cost most popular spring break destinations

Tags: usa, where-on-earth, destinations

I'm currently an exchange student in Cleveland, OH. Some friends of mine and I want to make a Cleveland - Miami round trip by car during spring break (7/3 to 16/3).  We are looking to meet up with other college students enjoying spring break during this time.

What are the most popular spring break destinations south of Charlotte, NC?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Why not ask your classmates?  There are destinations all around Florida and beyond and their destination is defined mostly by the amount of money they or their parents are willing to spend.  Some just go home to visit the folks.

Comment: The friends I'm doing this thing with are exchange students too :)
I'm actually in a quite nerdy university, so when I asked my classmates they where quite clueless and couldn't suggest anything other than Miami and Mexico.

Comment: I see this has been voted to close as opinion-based, but surely it could be objectively measured by statistics - ie, where do most of the spring breakers go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [LA Times](http://articles.latimes.com/2012/mar/02/news/la-trb-where-to-go-spring-break20120301), the top 10 Spring Break destinations, apparently based on number of travelers to these cities during spring break, in 2012 were:

1. Cancun, Mexico
2. Punta Cana,Dominican Republic
3. **Miami (South Beach)**
4. **Panama City Beach, Fla.**
5. Puerto Vallarta, Mexico
6. Acapulco, Mexico
7. Montego Bay/Negril, Jamaica
8. Nassau, Bahamas
9. Cabo San Lucas, Mexico
10. Las Vegas

Two of them, both in Florida, seem to match your criteria.